# Nested $http.get functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm building a MEAN stack app, where I need to return a logged in users email address, in order to pass it into a $http.get statement, as a parameter, in order to return data for display.

I am currently trying to do this in a factory, this is the endpoint I have for returning the current logged in user;

```
$http.get('/api/users/me') 
          .then(function(result) {
            userId = result.data.email;
          });
```

This endpoint works, and if I console.log within the function it will return the email of the logged in user, if I console.log outside, then it returns undefined.

I was wondering if it would be possible to either nest, or use .then or .success in order to pass the returned email address from the original $http.get into a second request, which would look something like this;

```
$http.get('/api/bets', {params: {"created_by": userId}});
```

Pretty new to Angular, so if you have any suggestions on where to start with a solution, it would be mighty helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You can return another promise from within the callback, and it will be chained:

```
$http.get('/api/users/me') 
      .then(function(result) {
        return $http.get('/api/bets', {params: {"created_by": result.data.email}});
      })
      .then(function(result){  
           //result of /api/bets 
      });
```

Comment: Thanks guys, this is awesome, and now I'm getting the right params passed in; 

config: Object
headers: Object
method: "GET"
paramSerializer: ngParamSerializer(params)
params: Object
created_by: "test@test.com"

however, it's still returning every object, regardless of the params, any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like that is something on the server side... Assuming you are using WebAPI, it might expect that you send a post instead of a get, or maybe the parameter does not match up with what is expected. Put a breakpoint in the server side handler to see what is there.

Answer (score 2):

Just chain the promises by returning another $http.get from within your first handler.

```
$http.get('/api/users/me') 
          .then(function(result) {
            userId = result.data.email;

            // make the next call
            return $http.get('/api/bets', {params: {"created_by": userId}});
          }).then(function (result) {
            // result of last call available here
          });
```